# Extract all text from field after and including a specific month in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is an example of a Note column I have in Snowflake. It can have multiple entries in a single note, each separated out by a date. What I would like to accomplish is to be able to extract all text with a date in a specific month/year from the Note. I have been attempting this by using REGEXP_SUBSTR(NOTE,'.8/../2022([^/]+)',1,1,'i') and it's getting me part way there, but it's not pulling out all instances of entries from August 2022. Currently when I run this through Snowflake it is pulling out the 8/10/2022 entry, which is weird because it skips the 8/1/2022.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example Note:
06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED
7/8/2020 - CREATED ACCOUNT
8/1/2022 - UPDATED AGREEMENT
08/10/2022 – RECEIVED COURTHOUSE DOC
8/11/2022 - DEUBANKS – RECEIVED TRANSFER

Desired Result:
8/1/2022 - UPDATED AGREEMENT
08/10/2022 – RECEIVED COURTHOUSE DOC
8/11/2022 - DEUBANKS – RECEIVED TRANSFER

Comment: Probably because you have 08 in 08/10/2022 and 8 in 8/1/2022 and the pattern is .8/../2022

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select regexp_extract_all('06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED 7/8/2020 - CREATED ACCOUNT 8/1/2022 - UPDATED AGREEMENT 08/10/2022 – RECEIVED COURTHOUSE DOC 8/11/2022 - DEUBANKS – RECEIVED TRANSFER'
                     ,'0?8\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}[\\W]+[\\w]+[\\W]+[\\w]+');
```

Comment: This is working in a way, but it is only pulling back two words after the date. My example only had 2 words, but in the real data it could have a large count of words after the date. Is there a way to pull back all text between dates?

Comment: Try this '0?8\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}[^\\d]+'

Comment: This would work except there are times that there are notes that include numbers, this is causing it to stop capturing as soon as it runs across a digit.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and I had the discretion to organize the data better for downstream reporting, I would use `regex` to modify the notes so I can split them to rows and parse dates and notes in separate columns. One way to do that is to pad all instance of dates with a reliable delimiter. I am using double pipes `||` , but you can choose whatever character/s you think are unlikely to appear in your data.

```
with cte(str) as 
(select '06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED 7/8/2020 - CREATED ACCOUNT 8/1/2022 - UPDATED AGREEMENT 08/10/2022 – RECEIVED COURTHOUSE DOC 8/11/2022 - DEUBANKS – RECEIVED TRANSFER 06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED'),

note_splitted as
(select *,
        try_to_date(regexp_substr(b.value,$$[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$$)) as note_date, 
        regexp_replace(b.value,$$[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}([^a-zA-Z0-9]*)$$) as note
 from cte a, lateral split_to_table(regexp_replace(str,$$([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})$$,'\|\|\\1'),'||') b
 where b.value<>'')

select str, note, note_date
from note_splitted
where note_date>='2020-08-01';
```

**Note**: Inside `regexp_replace`, we are using a replacement trick `'\|\|\\1'` that allows us to include the captured group `\\1` right after the replacement `\|\|`. This way, all instances of `month/day/year` become  `||month/day/year`, allowing us to demarcate beginning of the next note. This comes in handy when we split the notes to rows.

---

If you must have one row per note, you can modify the above to something like this.

```
with cte(str) as 
(select '06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED 7/8/2020 - CREATED ACCOUNT 8/1/2022 - UPDATED AGREEMENT 08/10/2022 – RECEIVED COURTHOUSE DOC 8/11/2022 - DEUBANKS – RECEIVED TRANSFER 06/17/2020 - PROVISIONED')

select str,
       listagg(b.value) as sub_note
from cte a, lateral split_to_table(regexp_replace(str,$$([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})$$,'\|\|\\1'),'||') b
where b.value rlike $$0?8/[0-9]{1,2}/2022.*$$
group by str
```

Comment: This looks really nice but unfortunately I have to keep the notes grouped in the single row. This is what I've come up with that seems to be working out for me. I'm a regexp newbie, so I wouldn't be able to explain why it works, but it seems to be doing the trick! regexp_extract_all(Note,'0?8\/[0-9]{1,2}\/2022 ([^*]*)((abc)+|$)',1,1 )

Comment: @BeAllgood I added in another approach in case it helps. BTW your regex won't work if you have another note after August 2020 but with an earlier date. You can test that with my CTE above